# Why am I receiving 'Invalid Hook Call' error in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm fairly new to React and am currently working on changing a functional component to a class, however I'm receiving the following error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

This appears to relate to line 11:

```
const { choices, setChoices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);
```

Any help would be much appreacited.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CategoryData from "./data/CategoryData";
import { ChoicesContext } from "../context/ChoicesProvider";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../images/logo.svg';
import { ReactComponent as WaterTechLogo } from '../images/water-tech-logo.svg';

class Applications extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { choices, setChoices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);

    return (
      <>
        <Link to="/">
          <Logo className="Logo" />
        </Link>
        <WaterTechLogo className="WaterTechLogo" />

        <div className="pageLinks">
          <div className="breadcrumb">Applications</div>
          <div className="backBtn"></div>
        </div>

        <div className="applications wrapper d-md-flex">
          <aside>
            <h2>Select an<br />Application</h2>
          </aside>

          <main>
            <div id="applicationsList">
              {CategoryData.map((cat, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="application">
                  <Link
                    onClick={() => setChoices({ ...choices, category: cat.name })}
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/waterType",
                      name: cat.name,
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={cat.imageURL} alt={cat.name} />
                    <h4 className="appTitle">{cat.name}</h4>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Applications;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly states that hooks can only be called inside functional component. However your Applications component is a class component and you are trying to use useContext in it.

Convert it into a functional component like

```
const Applications = () =>  {
    const { choices, setChoices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);

    return (
      <>
        <Link to="/">
          <Logo className="Logo" />
        </Link>
        <WaterTechLogo className="WaterTechLogo" />

        <div className="pageLinks">
          <div className="breadcrumb">Applications</div>
          <div className="backBtn"></div>
        </div>

        <div className="applications wrapper d-md-flex">
          <aside>
            <h2>Select an<br />Application</h2>
          </aside>

          <main>
            <div id="applicationsList">
              {CategoryData.map((cat, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="application">
                  <Link
                    onClick={() => setChoices({ ...choices, category: cat.name })}
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/waterType",
                      name: cat.name,
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={cat.imageURL} alt={cat.name} />
                    <h4 className="appTitle">{cat.name}</h4>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </>
    );
}

export default Applications;
```

The other solution is to use Context like like in class components by defining a static contextType property

```
class Applications extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ChoicesContext;
  render() {
    const { choices, setChoices } = this.context;

    return (
      <>
        <Link to="/">
          <Logo className="Logo" />
        </Link>
        <WaterTechLogo className="WaterTechLogo" />

        <div className="pageLinks">
          <div className="breadcrumb">Applications</div>
          <div className="backBtn"></div>
        </div>

        <div className="applications wrapper d-md-flex">
          <aside>
            <h2>Select an<br />Application</h2>
          </aside>

          <main>
            <div id="applicationsList">
              {CategoryData.map((cat, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="application">
                  <Link
                    onClick={() => setChoices({ ...choices, category: cat.name })}
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/waterType",
                      name: cat.name,
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={cat.imageURL} alt={cat.name} />
                    <h4 className="appTitle">{cat.name}</h4>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Applications;
```

Comment: As a note, there is a library that will let you add hooks to class components: https://github.com/salvoravida/react-universal-hooks, though I wouldn't necessarily recommend it

Comment: @ZacharyHaber yes, things that can be done with hooks can also be done with class components so it isn't essential to use a library just to use hooks in class components. Its not even recommended in react. Otherwise we wouldn't be seeing such errors being thrown :-)

Comment: Not necessarily true (that all things done with hooks can be done with class components), there is better composability and re-usability that hooks provide, which is the only reason I'd even contemplate using it on a component I can't convert to hooks and didn't want to wrap with a million HOCs for the hooks of interest. `useMemo` is also very convenient at times and much easier than doing the equivalent in a class component.

Comment: Sure, Its actually up to the user too. Sometimes functional components can be easier to use and sometimes class components.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hooks inside a class component. Only in function components.